# Consulta con dos tipos de datos INT y VARCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos tablas de las cuales selecciono un campo de cada una para la consulta y llenar el datagrid solo que me da errror por que el id esta en tipo int y la otra es una cadena de tipo varchar en la que tiene varios id registrados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: estos son los campos en las diferentes tablas id_com y place_id]

---

Es sql server 2012 y el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano gracias y  alanfcm no sabia eso de las como cual seria la mejor opcion y el query es:

```
SELECT  dbo.Temporal_Price.Place_Id, dbo.Temporal_Price.Gas_Price, 
 dbo.Temporal_Price.Tipo, dbo.Temporal_Price.Update_Time
FROM  dbo.Cliente INNER JOIN
      dbo.Temporal_Price ON dbo.Cliente.Id_Com1 = dbo.Temporal_Price.Place_Id
```

Comment: Se considera mala practica guardar datos separados por comas.  Cual es el query que estas tratando de hacer?

Comment: Agrega por favor el error que te está dando la consulta

Comment: Y también la versión de SQL Server que estás usando

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Es muy importante que leas los links que te pase. Ademas que seas mucho mas claro con  lo que estas pidiendo. Que tiene que ver que uno sea int y el otro varchar? que codigo te da error? que error?

Comment: No puedes convertir la cadena '5382, 8231, 8342' a entero, pq no representan un valor numérico en lo absoluto ya que tienen comas y espacio en su interior.

Comment: Es una mala practica hacer eso, te recomiendo hacer una tabla intermedia donde puedas poner cada valor en un nuevo row y ya después haces los JOIN que necesites.

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate si esta solución te sirve:

```
SELECT  
    dbo.Temporal_Price.Place_Id, 
    dbo.Temporal_Price.Gas_Price,
    dbo.Temporal_Price.Tipo, 
    dbo.Temporal_Price.Update_Time
 FROM  
  dbo.Cliente 
 INNER JOIN
  dbo.Temporal_Price ON 
  (
    dbo.Temporal_Price.Place_Id IN (
      SELECT t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)')
        FROM (
          SELECT x = CAST('<t>' + 
             REPLACE(dbo.Cliente.Id_Com1 , ',', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
        ) a
       CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c)
    )
  );
```

Basado en https://stackoverflow.com/a/30512923/1423096

de yapa un fidel : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6a1b6/1